# [Honor View 10 Lite][USB] Device not recognized by PC

Tags: usb, 9.0-pie

Looked everywhere around the net, followed any guide I was able to find, and now my last hope is here. As the title say I'm unable to successfully connect my device to any PC. What I already did ?

- Tested connection on Windows 10, Windows 7 and Kali. Windows not show any device connected, same for kali, using lsusb command.
- On the device, in Developers menu I've turned ON/OFF settings related to usb, changed the usb mode from Charge Only to any other option, but as soon as I exit the menu the settings change back to Charge Only, Debug USB OFF.
- I've also changed USB Port Settings in the ProjectMenu to Manufacture Mode/Google Mode.
- Removed, installed and updated to latest version HiSuite.
- I've tested with 6 different cables.

What I can think is the EMUI 9 update I did few days ago broke something or the connector is half dead and can only charge(weird). Any idea about any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I manged to get this working again, by enabling USB via Hi Suite.

1. Connect phone and open Hi Suite.
2. You should see a USB option for the device.
3. When selecting it, you should get the prompt on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but it seems it may have been dodgy USB leads. HiSuite would pop up on the computer when I connected to the PC but wouldn't connect. Tried uninstalling then re-installing HiSuite on the phone but still the same. Was about to factory reset the phine when I decided to try a different USB lead whuch worked